# Going mad trying to compile against OpenSSL/libcrypto

Tags: c++, node.js, cygwin, openssl, waf

I have been trying to do this for nearly 3 days now. Its driving me nuts.

As you can imagine I'm quite new to C++.

Can anyone give me step by step instructions to do a hello world program making use of a function in openssl and compile it from a cygwin shell on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to link with libcrypto. Append `-lcrypto` to your linker flags.

Comment: Thanks. Is this what you mean?

Comment: `ppp.cxxflags = ["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall", "-L/usr/lib", "-lssl", "-lcrypto"]`

Comment: Tried this, but with same result. Sounds like you are on the right track though.

Comment: Is there anything else I might need to do?

Comment: Where should the binaries be? I may need to build them and get them in the right place.

Comment: It seems that these flags are not really being used to compile your program, otherwise it should have worked. Could you confirm if they are really being used? E.g: by checking the command that invokes the linker.

Comment: I'm fairly sure they are. I think the system just cannot see the relevant binaries. They are probably not in the right place. Where should they be? What files are we actually talking about for OpenSSL. What extensions do the necessary binary files have?

Comment: I changed the build file and the process failed completely, so yes, this file is being used to kick off the compilation.

Comment: Did you get a different error after that change? Trying to answer your questions, Cygwin is a Linux-like environment, so these libraries are generally under /usr/lib, and their headers under /usr/include. GCC accepts -I and -L to extend the search to another directories. The dynamic library extension is .so, and to link with -lsomething, GCC (ld) expects to find /usr/lib/libsomething.so.

Comment: @Tom let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1092/discussion-between-jweyrich-and-tom)

Comment: I can't right now. (My girl is up now). But I will be back later if I can't solve the problem from your very helpful comments. Thankyou.